# Raphael JS Free Transform on selected object

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, transform

I am trying to use Raphael.js to dynamically create objects. e.g.:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas");
      var elements = [];
      elements.push(paper.rect(20,30,100,12).attr({fill:"orange"})); 
      elements.push(paper.path("m200,200l280,200l290,290z").attr({fill: "rgb(213,111,5)"})); 
      elements.push(paper.ellipse(340,100,90,40).attr({fill:"hsb(0.5,0.9,0.9)"}));
```

I then want to use Free Transform on every shape, but hide the bounding box and handles unless an individual shape is clicked on. So far, I have looped through every shape in the array in the array, applied Free Transform and hidden the handles:

```
for(var i in elements) {
    var ft = paper.freeTransform(elements[i],{draw:['bbox']})
    ft.hideHandles();
}
```

But I am struggling to add an event handler to each object that will show the handles on the shape that has been clicked, and hide it on the others.

I'd be extremely grateful for any advice!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with some examples code?

Comment: What do you have trouble with, adding the event handler or coding its content to do what you need ? The handler will be passed the clicked object as a parameter. From there you should be able to hide the bbox on everything except this one.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it!

It was less complex than I thought. I had been messing about with closures (Javascript isn't my first language), but my solution is:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas");
var elements = [];
elements.push(paper.rect(20,30,100,12).attr({fill:"orange"})); 
elements.push(paper.path("m200,200l280,200l290,290z").attr({fill: "rgb(213,111,5)"}));      
elements.push(paper.ellipse(340,100,90,40).attr({fill:"hsb(0.5,0.9,0.9)"}));

//add Free Transform to all elements
for(var i in elements) {
  var thisShape = elements[i];
  var ft = paper.freeTransform(thisShape,{draw:['bbox']});
  ft.hideHandles();
  thisShape.click(function(){
    paper.forEach(function(el) {
  if(el.freeTransform.handles.bbox != null)
    el.freeTransform.hideHandles();
});
this.freeTransform.showHandles();
  });
}
```

This doesn't seem like a very elegant solution, but it does the job. Is there a better way?